# Creating date function C++

Tags: c++, arrays, date, time

I'm working on this time, and they functions.
I'm trying to use correct numbers days in a specific month by using checkDay Function.
However, this is causing a runtime error saying "abort() has been called".
I believe there must be something wrong with this line "day = checkDay(day);"
, but not sure how to fix it. Thank you!!

```
void Date::increaseADay()
{
int temp;

second++;
if (second == 60)
{
    second = 0;
    ++minute;
}
if (minute == 60)
{
    minute = 0;
    ++hour;
}
if (hour == 24)
{
    hour = 0;
    ++day;
}

day = checkDay(day);

}





unsigned int Date::checkDay(int testDay) const
{
static const array< int, monthsPerYear + 1 > daysPerMonth =
{ 0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

// determine whether testDay is valid for specified month
if (testDay > 0 && testDay <= daysPerMonth[month])
    return testDay;

// February 29 check for leap year 
if (month == 2 && testDay == 29 && (year % 400 == 0 ||
    (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0)))
    return testDay;

throw invalid_argument("Invalid day for current month and year");
 } // end function checkDay
```

Comment: Please edit and tag the language you are using

Comment: where is variable `month` defined and where is it's value set? Please provide that portion of code, too. Have you stepped through your program with the debugger?

Comment: You should use a debugger to check where your code is failing and why. Also you might want to watch this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY) and rethink if you really want to write your own date class or rather use [`std::chrono`](http://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono)

Comment: The variables `day`, `second` and `month` are not declared anywhere. My wild guess would be, that the value inside `month` is bigger than the size of the array at the instruction `daysPerMonth[month]` in the function `checkDay`.